# Why false|(!!1)===1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

`!!` is used to cast as Boolean in JavaScript, that is, `!!1 === true`.

However, when I do  `false|(!!1)` it give me `1`, but it should equal to `false|true===true`.

Is it a bug or a feature in JavaScript?

I tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: `|` operates on numbers (specifically bits) and `false|true` becomes `0|1` which is `=== 1`. I think you meant `false||(!!1)` (notice `||` - two of them). Closing as typo.

Comment: Doesn't work for Chrome: `false|(!!1) === 1` -> `0`

Comment: It gives 1 with false|true --> http://jsfiddle.net/jpuxc7j8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wen you apply | on false|true then it becomes numbers ie, false as 0 and 1 as true. | is **[bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)** and is mostly applied on bits.

```
alert(false|true);
```

Output

```
1
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jpuxc7j8/)

And if you use || then it returns true

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jpuxc7j8/1/)